# Xamarin.Android device requirements

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Does Xamarin.Android have any requirements against the device, like a minimum Android version or for example at least an ARMv7 CPU?

Comment: This questions sounds like _off-topic_. Would be better in http://superuser.com/?

Comment: This is a real question and does not violate the rules.  The answer accepted is a good one, and it is evidence the question is a real question.  I think the closers are over-zealous.  It is a shame no one else got to answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Android requires you to build for API Level 4 (Android 1.6) or higher. The supported architectures are x86, armeabi and armeabi-v7a (the same as native Android development)